# Which Javascript Runtime to use for a Rails 3.1 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

Environment: Rails 3.1, Passenger, Ubunut, MySQL

I am using the uglifier gem and the other asset pipeline functionality of Rails 3.1. If I understand the documentation correctly, then I need the execjs gem which in return requires a javascript runtime. On the EXCJS pages it lists a couple of runtimes that it supports, such as

```
therubyracer
therubyrhino
Node.js
etc...
```

Is there a general recommended platform to use for Ubuntu?

Second part of the question: does the javaruntime have an impact on the memory usage of the ruby processes triggered by Passenger?

Comment: Did you finally got a decision on that? I am interested in this question too.

Comment: Nope, no response whatsoever.